Has anyone translated Commentary of Vallabhacharya on Gita?
There must be a commentary of Shree Vallabhacharya on Shree Gita as part of his Prasthatrayi. I was told that it's called Tatvarth Deepika. I could find its Sanskrit version online. But I could not find any translation of it.
Does anyone know if any translation of the commentary exists?
